# Hibernate lock rows in update

Tags: hibernate

I have to change several records, allocate vehicles on trips.

I need to validate that a vehicle is not in two places at the same time, and this validation takes a few seconds.

So I need to block this data from being changed by another user while the allocation of vehicles at all trips is not complete.

Could anyone help me, I use hibernate 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the sql statement. Instead of running hibernate update for each record, I made a cascade change and put the business rule before making the change.

```
@Override
public void substituirViagensLote(TrEmpresaReguladora er, TrViagem v, String... args) throws DaoException {
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("UPDATE TrViagem SET "
                                    + " viagDataAlteracao = TO_DATE('" + args[0] + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),"
    str.append(" veicCodigo.veicCodigo = " + Long.parseLong(args[3]) + ",");
    str.append(" WHERE 1=1");
    str.append(" AND viagCodigo IN (" + args[6] + ")");

    executeHql(v, OperacaoEnum.UPDATE, str.toString());
}
```